# Can I remove grub by connecting the HDD to another computer?

Tags: grub

Related question is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/948428/computer-does-not-boot-from-optical-drive-or-from-usb/948448#948448).

TL;DR: had dual boot, reset to factory settings on Windows, and didn't remove Ubuntu and grub first. Now I'm stuck with grub rescue prompt.

Can I remove grub manually when the HDD is connected to another computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Insert your Windows 7 disc and boot from it.
2) Keep going through the steps until you reach a Repair option, select it.
3) In "System Restore Options" click Command Prompt.
4) Run: Bootrec.exe /FixBoot
5) Run: Bootrec.exe /FixMBR

Other install discs such as XP, Win8 and Win10 can also restore/repair the master boot record but the process may be slightly diffrent then.

For more information:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub

Comment: Thanks for the message, but this doesn't really help because it doesn't answer the question directly. I can't boot into something else. However, I found the solution and will post it as a separate answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the [Ease US Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/landing/home-download.htm) free edition. You have to download the free edition from the comparison page, otherwise they want to make you download the free trial to the pro version.

I connected the HDD to another computer, ran the Partition Tool from there, and then selected "Drive -> Rebuild MBR". After that I had to click on "Apply", plug the HDD back into my computer and everything was OK.

[Here's the link](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/rebuild-mbr.htm) to the page where they explain how to do this, together with screenshots and additional info.

I'm not associated with them in any way. Hope this doesn't break any rules, I'm posting this only because it solved my issue, and might help others as well.